# How to customize response Error 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, web-services, url, jetty, jetty-9

I have a web service provided by jetty.
How can i filter URL with illegal characters?

I can not control some return information when the request URL has illegal characters.

actually, i want to return some specific info when the URL is invalid.
for example: i added a filter in my application to validate the URL, if illegal then i will return defined info.

but, I can not filter some URL like "%adsasd", it seem be handled by jetty.

> curl -v -X PUT -u user:password 'http://myip.com:8080/%adsasd'

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user'
> PUT /%adsasd HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNDU2
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Accept: */*
> Host:127.0.0.1:8080
>  < HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 
   < Content-Length: 0
* Server Jetty(9.0.6.v20130930) is not blacklisted 
   < Server: Jetty(9.0.6.v20130930) < 
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error response from Jetty

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

indicates that Jetty did detect that as a bad URL and rejected it.

As for how to customize this, that is really tricky, mainly due to how early in the processing of this specific request it occurs in.

This kind of error (`400 Bad Request`) occurs during the parsing of the raw incoming http request, well before the server container has even attempted to figure out what context to talk to.

There is no way to have a custom error handler in a specific webapp context handle this sort of fundamental http error.  As the server has yet to figure out what context to even talk to.

There is also no way at the server side (even at a global level) to customize this error message.

If you want such a feature, [please file a feature request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Jetty&format=guided).

Comment: yes, but can i handle the bad URL and reject with custom information?for example: return a json string that {"error":"you need check your URL"} etc.

Comment: I want to reject bad URL by my filter not jetty container.but, now the request with bad URL rejected by jetty, not sent to my application.

Comment: As the answer points out, since this is so fundamentally bad, there is no way for jetty to know what context (ie, your webapp) to send it to, it will never be sent down an application on your server, its too broken to be processed.  This is an early protocol error.  Valid HTTP clients should handle this error based on the HTTP Response code, not the body content.